# If $7\sin^2A-3\cos^2A=4$, then $\tan A\neq\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

> If $7\sin^2A-3\cos^2A=4$, then we have to show that $\tan A=\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

The textbook approaches this by substituting $\sin^2A=1-\cos^2A$ and that method does(not) work.

$7\sin^2A-3\cos^2A=4$

$\implies  7\sin^2A-3(1-\sin^2A)=4$ {contains a sign error)

$\implies \sin^2a=\dfrac{1}{4}$

$\implies \cos^2A=1-\sin^2A=\dfrac{3}{4}$

Then, $\tan^2A=\dfrac{\sin^2A}{\cos^2A}=\dfrac{1}{3}$

$\implies \tan A=\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

But what's wrong with mine?(nothing)

$7\sin^2A-3\cos^2A=4(\sin^2A+\cos^2A)$

$\implies 3\sin^2A=7\cos^2A$

$\implies \dfrac{\sin^2A}{\cos^2A}=\dfrac{7}{3}$

$\implies \tan^2A=\dfrac{7}{3}$

$\implies \tan A=\sqrt{\dfrac{7}{3}}$

EDIT:Actually,the  textbook(as usual) made a sign error in the second line.Ignore it.My solution is correct.

Comment: Your second line is wrong; developing, you have $10 \sin ^2(A)=7$

Comment: @Claude,yes,I was stupid not to have seen that.Ty.

Comment: This kind of mistakes happen to everybody ! Don't worry. Cheers.

Comment: That was a good one! And here I was, trying to crack the second approach.

Comment: So they should have put a plus in the original formula, $7\sin^2A+3\cos^2A=4$.

Comment: What textbook are you using that has these kinds of errors?  (Someone didn't even bother trying their "solution" in the original equation...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book made a sign error in the second line.My method is correct.